# asp.net RESX Files

Tags: asp.net

hi am new to resource file and  my problem is in my web-from i want to print a paragraph from resource file in aspx file am writing below code for resx for asp controls.  but i don't know how to write a resource in multi line   and how to access that data from my webpage using paragraph

tag

```
 <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align: center">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="20pt" 
                            style="text-align: center" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource1, Headerlabel %>"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="<%$Resources:Resource1,usernamelabel %>"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style4">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ToolTip="<%$Resources:Resource1,Usertooltip %>"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
                            ErrorMessage="<%$Resources:Resource1,userreq %>" 
                            ControlToValidate="TextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

please tell me how to write resource in multi line

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox 
ID="txtReturn" 
runat="server" 
Rows="5" 
TextMode="MultiLine" 
Width="490px"
ToolTip="<%$Resources:Resource1,Usertooltip %>"
Text="<%$Resources:Resource1,usernamelabel %>
></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: how to  put \n new line character in resource for presenting a paragraph

Comment: If you are in the Visual Studio Resource Editor, you can press SHIFT+ENTER. That should do it.

Comment: Thank u for ur replay but in my webfrom the text box is aapiring with scroller is thr any other way to display my resx text as  paragraph    in <P></P>

Comment: What happens is you put \n in the text?